# switch language in agularjs 1.4.9

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-directive

i want to select language from dropdown list and also need to select default language.
below is the link where i found the code but it is switching a language with buttons.
http://embed.plnkr.co/h7qUlY/

Comment: So go ahead and make a drop down and then if you run into specific problems with it, ask. StackOverflow isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I agree with Mike Feltman. But as I had worked on it earlier.

`<select ng-model="data.defaultLanguage" ng-change="switchLanguage()">
    <option value="de_DE" translate>LANG_DE_DE</option>
    <option value="en_US" translate>LANG_EN_US</option>
</select>`

Controller:

```
$translate.use('en_US');
$scope.data={};
$scope.data.defaultLanguage="en_US";
$scope.switchLanguage = function() {
  alert("called");
  $translate.use($scope.data.defaultLanguage);
};
```